# URI Regex Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex for my HTML input which will strict the user with some conditions.
(Usually I am writing codes to break up the string - so i only know the basics of regex and couldn't achieve that)

EXAMPLE:

A good input will look like this -

```
/account/{AccountID}/details
```

While a bad input will be like one of those -

```
/account{/{AccountID}/details
```

**nor**

```
/account/{{AccountID/details
```

In words :

after '/' :
Accept a camelCase string
OR
Accept '{' With Pascal String (only letters) after it and must close with '}'
AND
'{' can only be after '/'
AND
after '}' :
only '/' will be acceptable
OR
String end.

If this looks to complicated to achieve by regex, I will write it as a code.

Thanks for the helpers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Added more test cases and updated the regular expression, all working.

The previous answer doesn't take into account camel casing and Pascal casing and allows for numbers and underscores that you want to filter out. My proposal is the following:

```regex
/^\/account(\/[a-zA-Z]+)*(\/\{[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\})*(\/[a-zA-Z]+)?\/?$/
```

this works if I understood you syntax correctly:

```
/camelCase/{PascalCase}/camelCase/
```

If not, just let me know, I'll update my improvised unit tests in the snippet below accordingly:

```js
const re = /^\/account(\/[a-zA-Z]+)*(\/\{[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\})*(\/[a-zA-Z]+)?\/?$/;
const testCases = [
  {
    testString: '/account/{AccountID}/details',
    isValid: true,
  },
  {
    testString: '/account{/AccountID}/details',
    isValid: false,
  },
  {
    testString: '/account/{{AccountID/details',
    isValid: false,
  },
  {
    testString: '/account/{AccountID}',
    isValid: true,
  },
  {
    testString: '/account',
    isValid: true,
  },
  {
    testString: '/account/details/transactions/{AccountID}/{OtherParameter}/',
    isValid: true,
  },
];

testCases.forEach((testCase, i) => {
  const passed = re.test(testCase.testString);
  console.log(
    `${passed === testCase.isValid ? 'PASSED' : 'FAILED'}: Case ${i + 1} is ${
      testCase.isValid ? 'valid' : 'not valid'
    }`
  );
});
```

Let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: OK so i tried the regex and YES it works exactly as i wanted on my example.
The thing is that i want it to be a regex for all of my API requests while i dont know how many resources will be and how many parameters, and i also dont know the correct order..
Example : 
/account/{AccountID} 
OR
/account 
OR
/account/details/transactions/{AccountID}/{OtherParameter}

Should all be correct.. 

How do i implement this?

Comment: Can you share more valid and invalid inputs? I can test them all through my snippet and adapt the regex accordingly.

Comment: I updated my comment to be more detailed. Thank you in advance

Comment: @user3469465 Added your test cases and updated the regex. Let me know if this works. Or just keep them coming :)

Comment: I changed it a bit because the issue was with the Example of :       
/account/details/{AccountID}/transactions/{TransactionID}      
The new RegEx i wrote is this :     
^\/account(\/[a-zA-Z]+)*(\/\{[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\})*(\/[a-zA-Z]+)*(\/\{[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\})*?\/?$

Anyway i couldn't do it without your help, so thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate it !

Comment: I'm glad you got the hang of the unit testing approach and were able to figure out the last update yourself, congrats!

Answer (score 1):

The regex can be ^((\/\w+)|(\/\{\w+\}))+\/?$

Explanation:

```
^ -> begin of the string
$ -> end of the string 
\/\w+ -> matches /letersNumbersUnderscores
\/\{\w+\} -> the same as previous, but with { after / and } at the end
| -> OR operator with above expressions, to math /text or /{text}
(...)+ -> repeat one or more times the matches
\/?$ -> matches the / and the end (if present)
```

I tested the values:

```
/account/{AccountID}/details   -> MATCH
/account/{AccountID}/details/  -> MATCH
/account{/{AccountID}/details  -> NOT MATCH
/account/{{AccountID/details   -> NOT MATCH
```

Comment: Works fine for me, Thanks !!